# ViewPager inside ExpandableListView click Listener not working

Tags: android

I have a custom ViewPager inside my ExpandableListView, the click listener does not fire, is there any idea how to do it? I know I can add the click listener inside the adapater but I would rather not.

the custom pager

```
public class CustomPager extends ViewPager {


/**
 * the last x position
 */
private float lastX;

/**
 * if the first swipe was from left to right (->), dont listen to swipes from the right
 */
private boolean slidingLeft;

/**
 * if the first swipe was from right to left (<-), dont listen to swipes from the left
 */
private boolean slidingRight;

public CustomPager(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public CustomPager(final Context context) {
    super(context);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(final MotionEvent ev) {
    final int action = ev.getAction();
    switch (action) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

            // Disallow parent ViewPager to intercept touch events.
            this.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);

            // save the current x position
            this.lastX = ev.getX();

            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            // Allow parent ViewPager to intercept touch events.
            this.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);

            // save the current x position
            this.lastX = ev.getX();

            // reset swipe actions
            this.slidingLeft = false;
            this.slidingRight = false;

            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            /*
             * if this is the first standing_item, scrolling from left to
             * right should navigate in the surrounding ViewPager
             */
            if (this.getCurrentItem() == 0) {
                // swiping from left to right (->)?
                if (this.lastX <= ev.getX() && !this.slidingRight) {
                    // make the parent touch interception active -> parent pager can swipe
                    this.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
                } else {
                    /*
                     * if the first swipe was from right to left, dont listen to swipes
                     * from left to right. this fixes glitches where the user first swipes
                     * right, then left and the scrolling state gets reset
                     */
                    this.slidingRight = true;

                    // save the current x position
                    this.lastX = ev.getX();
                    this.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                }
            } else
            /*
             * if this is the last standing_item, scrolling from right to
             * left should navigate in the surrounding ViewPager
             */
                if (this.getCurrentItem() == this.getAdapter().getCount() - 1) {
                    // swiping from right to left (<-)?
                    if (this.lastX >= ev.getX() && !this.slidingLeft) {
                        // make the parent touch interception active -> parent pager can swipe
                        this.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                    } else {
                    /*
                     * if the first swipe was from left to right, dont listen to swipes
                     * from right to left. this fixes glitches where the user first swipes
                     * left, then right and the scrolling state gets reset
                     */
                        this.slidingLeft = true;

                        // save the current x position
                        this.lastX = ev.getX();
                        this.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                    }
                }

            break;
    }

    super.onTouchEvent(ev);
    return true;
}


@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)
{
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

    int height = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < getChildCount(); i++)
    {
        View child = getChildAt(i);
        child.measure(widthMeasureSpec, MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
        int h = child.getMeasuredHeight();
        if(h > height) height = h;
    }

    heightMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(height, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);

    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
}
```

}

inflating it inside my adapater

```
        if (groupPosition == 0) {
        final HeaderHolder viewHolder;
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.season_team_fixtures_item, null);
        viewHolder = new HeaderHolder();
        viewHolder.customIndicator = (CircleIndicator) convertView.findViewById(R.id.indicator_custom);
        viewHolder.viewPager = (CustomPager) convertView.findViewById(R.id.pager);
        viewHolder.seeAll = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.AllFixtures);
        viewHolder.viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        viewHolder.customIndicator.setViewPager(itemView.viewPager);
```

season_team_fixtures_item layot

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/appBackground">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/card1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/linlaHeaderProgress"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:indeterminate="true"
        android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/progress_drawable"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <com.redeagle07.egyptianleague.teams.season.CustomPager
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/white_frame"
            android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true" />

        <me.relex.circleindicator.CircleIndicator
            android:id="@+id/indicator_custom"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="4dp"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            app:ci_animator="@animator/indicator_animator"
            app:ci_animator_reverse="@animator/indicator_animator_reverse"
            app:ci_drawable="@drawable/black_radius_square" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/AllFixtures"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/white_frame"
            android:gravity="end"
            android:paddingLeft="2dp"
            android:textColor="@color/ColorPrimaryDark"
            android:paddingRight="2dp"
            android:text="@string/Allfixtures"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textSize="15sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Appreciate the help guys, thanks in advance

Comment: take a look at the following example, it works: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24083886/expandablelistview-in-fragment-issue/24159659#24159659. Please upvote the answer if it has helpd you.

Comment: @codedByMi do you understand the differences between *ViewPager inside ExpandableListView* and *ExpandableListView inside ViewPager*

Comment: I was just trying to help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use         `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` in parent FrameLayout instead of linearlayout